# Can't read value from existing key

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I can't read a value from a reg key.. For some weird reason. The path is correct.. And the key exist. I have no idea why it can't read it.

Bit of code that I have(that read the registry)

```
string local  = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.ToString();
        string javaRegPath = "\\SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\";
        if (javaRegPath != null)
        {
            string javaVersion = Registry.readReg(local + javaRegPath, "CurrentVersion").ToString();
            string javaHome = Registry.readReg(javaRegPath + "\\" + javaVersion, "JavaHome").ToString();
            return javaHome;
        }
```

Registry.cs (read)

```
public static object readReg(string keyPath, string keyName)
    {
        key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyPath);
        return  key.GetValue(keyName);
    }
```

And here is an image from Registry Editor. To verify the paths and so on.
[registry http://bumisworld.eu/reg.png](http://bumisworld.eu/reg.png)

But it just returns a NPE...

Message:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in The Bukkit GUI Project.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[registry http://bumisworld.eu/locals2.png](http://bumisworld.eu/locals2.png)

Any help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of problems that I can see.

Firstly `readReg` is actually calling `OpenSubKey` on `Registry.CurrentUser`. That reads from `HKCU`. You need to use from `Registry.LocalMachine` for `HKLM`. Pass the root key to `readReg` as an extra parameter.

On top of that you will likely be caught out by the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your 32 bit process (well, I assume your process is 32 bit) is redirected to the 32 bit view of the registry. But the key you are looking for is in the 64 bit view of the registry.

In other words your attempt to access `HKLM\Software` is being redirected to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`.

Use the [`RegistryView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) enumeration to allow your 32 bit process to access the 64 bit view of the registry.

---

Your `readReg` function should also be modified to check for errors in the call to `OpenSubKey`. That method can return `null`. You should deal with that scenario in a cleaner way then let a `NullReferenceException` be thrown.

Comment: The problem might also be that the OP is opening HKLM with `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Well, that is embarrassing. How did I miss that? Now fixed.

Comment: I saw that myself. But with your answer it also helped me. So thank you.